# Android in-app billing crashing sometimes/working sometimes

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm trying to setup in-app billing for my app and I just edit the TrivialDrive's (only needed gas purchase so i delete other purchase codes). so the first time i run it it worked perfectly and I even done the purchase. but the next time i run it (i'm 100% sure i didn't change any code) when i select purchase button the app just crashes!

i tried: `invalidate and restart` android studio-restarting my phone but nothing changes.

```
>     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3688)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4293)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17535)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3683)
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4293) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17535) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                 at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't start async
> operation (launchPurchaseFlow) because another async operation(refresh
> inventory) is in progress.
>                                                                                 at util.IabHelper.flagStartAsync(IabHelper.java:819)
>                                                                                 at util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:373)
>                                                                                 at util.IabHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(IabHelper.java:338)
>                                                                                 at
> kalamat.fun4ever.com.word2.buying.onBuyGasButtonClicked(buying.java:209)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3683) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4293) 
>                                                                                 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17535) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) 
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                 at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
>                                                                                 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)  12-01 21:15:29.052
> 27771-27777/kalamat.fun4ever.com.word2 D/jdwp: processIncoming
```

this is 'buying.java:209'  :

```
  mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, RC_REQUEST,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
```

Answer (score 0):

because another operation not finished,maybe you have disconnected with google servers.check if the mservices is null,when the crash happened.